# integrating google place api in android app

Tags: android

i am following this link

http://ddewaele.blogspot.in/2011/05/introducing-google-places-api.html

and i downloaded sample code for google place api

https://github.com/tuthan/Google-Place-Api-Demo

when i run the project and click on button it force close and error at logcat

> com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpTransport', referenced
>   from method hung.vo.PlaceRequest.
>
> ```
> Could not find class 'hung.vo.PlaceRequest$1', referenced from method hung.vo.PlaceRequest.createRequestFactory
>
> Could not find class 'com.google.api.client.http.GenericUrl', referenced from method hung.vo.PlaceRequest.performSearch
>
> Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: hung.vo.PlaceRequest hung.vo.hung.vo.GooglePlaceActivity$SearchSrv.doInBackground(GooglePlaceActivity.java:36)
> ```
>
> and in GooglePlaceActivity line 36 is
>
> pl = new PlaceRequest().performSearch();

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in android manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```